# What is the suitable preposition which come after the verb "hassle"?

Tags: verbs, prepositions, expressions

Should we say, A hassles with B or A hassles to B?

What is the right expression?

Comment: Make some effort of your own and show it proudly here, so the others will be motivated to help. :) Also, Never post a question with capitalization, spacing and other errors.

Comment: Are you sure you mean *hassling* and not *haggling* ("Dispute or bargain persistently, esp. over the cost of something.")?

Comment: Assuming you truly meant "hassles" and not "haggles", "hassles" does not get a preposition - it stands alone: ***"A hassled B"***.  Think of it like the words "shoved" or "provoked" . . .A shoved B because B provoked A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither. *[Hassle](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hassle)* can be a transitive verb, so you can just say *A hassles B*.

Answer (score 2):

A hassles with B is grammatical:

> hassle v.intr. To argue or fight: customers hassling with merchants
>   over high prices. (AHD)

(though this example arguably uses 'hassling' adjectivally;

in 'the customers were hassling with merchants over high prices', *hassling* is indisputably verbal.)

But I'd guess the transitive usage is more common (but it does have a different shade of meaning).

Comment: -1 "customers hassling with merchants over high prices" seems to be the only instance of the phrase "customers hassling with" in the entire Google Search. This is apparently a mistaken use of *hassling* for *haggling*. See: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hassling+with%2C+haggling+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: You'd better give the -1 to the AHD then. I was assuming they'd done their usual research before endorsing the usage. Oh, and Collins agree. Perhaps your research is more reliable?

Comment: Collins does label it as [informal](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/hassle). Still, even though it may sound a bit unnatural to those who haven't heard it before, there it is. Maybe _customers hassling with_ is rare because most businessfolks follow the adage that the customer is always right. ;^) Nice piece of research. P.S. "Lucas was tired of hassling with someone he both loved and hated." (from a 1999 biography of George Lucas)

Answer (score 1):

Neither. A *hassles* B or A *is hassling* B.